# Rails 4.0.2 dependency mime-types (~> 1.16) is conflicting with other tools using mime-types 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

When trying to install the Mechanize gem, I get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.2) ruby depends on
      mime-types (~> 1.16) ruby

    mechanize (~> 2.7.3) ruby depends on
      mime-types (2.0)
```

Now I understand that it's because rails depends on `mime-types ~1.16` and Mechanize `mime-types 2.0` but is there no way to get those two to play nicely together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `mechanize ~> 2.6.0` for now and you should be okay until the Rails team can update their gem requirements for mime-types.

Check https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc to see if any of the revisions after 2.6.0 fix bugs or add features that may be important to you.